# selenium webdriver : How to click on particular button having classes applied to each. Unable to find exact x-path

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Q. Same kind of class applied to all Download button,How to distinct them from each other? Let's say i want to click on 3rd number of download button. Find a xpath for that button.

I have tried this but it's common for all.

```
//div[@class='statement-download']
```

[image]

[image]

```
    <div class="statement-download">
       <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-outline btn-default mb-0" type="button">
       <i class="mdi mdi-download m-r-5"></i>
       <span>Download</span>
       </button>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `index` of the parent `div`.

```
//div[@class='statement-card'][3]/div[@class='statement-download']
```

Comment: Thanks buddy for knowledge sharing.

Answer (score 0):

For 3rd, try following `xpath`:

```
(//div[@class='statement-download'])[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date as a starting point

```
date = 'July 2048'
//div[.='{date}']/following-sibling::div[@class='statement-download']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a better way you can do it by using loops if you have multiple operations

```
        List<WebElement> statementdownload = 
       driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='statement-download']"));

        for (int i=0;i<statementdownload.size();i++) {
            statementdownload.get(i).click();
            statementdownload.get(i).getText();

           // You can use your condition here

             }
```